# What does "synchronize" in IntelliJ IDEA do?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, there is an action called **Synchronize**, under `File > Synchronize`.

What exactly does it do? Is it related to VCS or IntelliJ's edit history? How can I use this action >_<

[image: "Synchronize" appearing as entry in list of actions]

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203332290-Synchronise-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It forces IntelliJ to process the latest changes from the file system. Normally the changes are processed automatically, so the action does not do anything.